# Cakephp 3 with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, cakephp-3.0

I am writing RESTful API using cakephp 3.6 for SQL Server 2012. Some API's created and working fine.

But unfortunately not for one table. This table have primary key but its value is not auto incremented. When I am assigning its value API its generating error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'AccountsLive.dbo.Books'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

I can't keep its primary key auto incremented.

When I create view to add it from browser. It does not create field for `Id field`. Then I try to create input field for Id field, its not going to display it on books input form.

Please help me to solve this issue, I will be thankful to you.

Comment: @marc_s please refer to this link to just check "R2" with SQL Server https://www.microsoft.com/en-eg/download/details.aspx?id=30438

Comment: That 's **2008 R2** which does in fact exist - not "2012 R2" as you had used (which does **NOT** exist)

Comment: Sorry @marc_s, its my mistake.

Comment: From the question, it wasn't quite clear which version you use - the title said "2012 R2" , while the tag said "2008 R2" .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption is that your id columns will be auto-incrementing. If there's a good reason(*) why you can't do that here, you'll need to add the input field (as you found), and also add it to the [`_accessible`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment) list in the `Book` entity.

(*) The number of situations where having your id column not auto-incrementing (and not a UUID) makes sense is really very small. Be very sure that this really does apply to you, as it moves all responsibility for avoiding overwriting records due to duplication onto you instead of the database.

Comment: I have try it with the input field with this code echo $this->Form->input('id', array ('type'=>'text')); , but not luck, first time its save 0 to Id field and second time it gives error for Integrity constraint violation.

Comment: Have you changed the `_accessible` list? The default version of that will NOT allow patching into the primary key field, so it'll be left as null in your entity.